# Image compressing Application

Tags: java, image, swing, compression

**Error in UI, unable to pass the data in 2 textfields or the paths which user selects when Button is clicked for compressing the image.**

Here is the code :

```
    // this is the button when clicked should compress the image 
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {              
        File imageFile = new File("myimage.jpg");
        File compressedImageFile = new File("myimage_compressed.jpg");

         try
         {
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(imageFile);
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(compressedImageFile);
            float quality = 0.5f;

            // create a BufferedImage as the result of decoding the supplied InputStream
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(is);

            // get all image writers for JPG format
            Iterator<ImageWriter> writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg");

            if (!writers.hasNext())
                throw new IllegalStateException("No writers found");
            ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter) writers.next();
            ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(os);
            writer.setOutput(ios);

            ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();

            // compress to a given quality
            param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
            param.setCompressionQuality(quality);

            // appends a complete image stream containing a single image and
            //associated stream and image metadata and thumbnails to the output
            writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), param);

            // close all streams
            is.close();
            os.close();
            ios.close();
            writer.dispose();
     }
     catch(IOException e)
     {
         System.out.println(e);
     }

} 


// this is the  button for choosing an image file 
private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {   
    JFileChooser chooser=new JFileChooser();
    FileNameExtensionFilter imgfilter=new FileNameExtensionFilter("Image files", "jpg");

    chooser.setFileFilter(imgfilter);
    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

    File f=chooser.getSelectedFile();
    String filename=f.getAbsolutePath();

    jTextField1.setText(filename); 
}



// this is the button  for choosing the destination folder for compressed  image to be saved                                      

private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    JFileChooser chooser=new JFileChooser();
    FileNameExtensionFilter imgfilter=new FileNameExtensionFilter("Image files", "jpg");
    chooser.setFileFilter(imgfilter);
    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    File f=chooser.getSelectedFile();
    String filename=f.getAbsolutePath();
    jTextField1.setText(filename);
}
```

In this I have two textfields and two buttons one button  for selecting the image from m/c and other button for  choosing the destination folder where the image has to be saved.

And a third Button for compressing the image file.

Comment: Please include (a part of) your code and say specifically what goes wrong. Otherwise it's hard for us to help you.

Comment: You are saying 2 buttons and explaining the use of 3 buttons

Comment: i am sorry for that but i meant two butons for choosing the location  and saving for the location and the third button for compressing the img file

Comment: *"And a third Button for compressing the image file."*  ..and your question is?

Answer (score 0):

Your code in section

```
// this is the  button for choosing an image file
```

and in section

```
// this is the button  for choosing the destination folder for compressed  image to be saved
```

is exactly same, the `jButton6` should be change and the `jtextfield1` should be changed according to your UI.

It would solve the issue I guess.

Good Luck

Comment: File imageFile = new File("myimage.jpg");

      File compressedImageFile = new File("myimage_compressed.jpg");
Here is want to pass the path  which user chooses by clicking the buttons for source folder where image is present and where the new image will be saved